# Freeze User who is logged in

Tags: user-management

If I freeze a user and if he is already logged into Salesforce, does he lose access? Or can he access it as long as he doesn't logout?

Comment: you could just deactivate the user and then reactivate again, thus forcing a new SessionId and then freeze the user.

Comment: This particular scenario is not documented clearly. I will think the best way to confirm this is to test it out.

Comment: @akarnid the reason I didn't deactivated is because there are certain processes I need to follow before deactivating. So I freezed the user in the meantime. However, I don't want the user to access Salesforce while frozen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a quick test in my DE Org, if an admin Freezes a User while the User is already logged in and accessing Salesforce, the User session is immediately terminated. The User cannot navigate to any other page/tab within the application once Frozen. The User is presented with a message as below.

[image]

Incorporating @sfdcfox's comment: The behavior is same if a User is deactivated.

Comment: Same behavior if you deactivate the user, too.

Comment: Good to know, will add your feedback in the answer to make it more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce checks the session's validity with every transaction. This means that if the user tries to continue working outside their Login Hours, while Frozen or deactivated, or if the IP address changes and "Lock session to IP address" changes, they will not be able to access Salesforce. There's no way to continue using a session if you're not allowed in the system for any security policy.